# PHP - file_get_html not returning anything

Tags: php

I am trying to scrape data from [this site](https://destinytracker.com/d2/profile/pc/Saenai-2940), using "inspect" I am checking the class of the div, but when I try to get it, it doesn't display anything:

Trying to get the "Diamond" below "Supremacy".

What I am using:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$memberName = $_GET['memberName'];
$html = file_get_html('https://destinytracker.com/d2/profile/pc/'.$memberName.'');

preg_match("/<div id=\"dtr-rating\".*span>/", $html, $data);

var_dump($data);

?>
```

Comment: What do you think `file_get_html` returns?  Not a string. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` will tell you stuff.

Comment: Are you looking for `file_get_contents()`?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, simple_html_dom is a package available on SourceForge at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.  See the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

`file_get_html()`, from simple_html_dom, does not return a string; it returns an object that has methods you can call to traverse the HTML document.  To get a string from the object, do:

```
$url = https://destinytracker.com/d2/profile/pc/'.$memberName;
$html_str = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
```

But if you are going to do that, you might as well just do:

```
$html_str = file_get_contents($url);
```

and then run your regex on `$html_str`.

BUT ... if you want to use the power of simple_html_dom ...

```
$html_obj = file_get_html($url);
$the_div = $html_obj->find('div[id=dtr-rating]', 0);
$inner_str = $the_div->innertext;
```

I'm not sure how to do exactly what you want, because when I look at the source of the web link you provided, I cannot find a `<div>` with `id="dtr-rating"`.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is about using simple_html_dom.  After looking at the HTML doc in more detail, I see the problem is different than I first thought (I'll leave it there for pointers on better use of simple_html_dom).

I see that the web page you are scraping is a VueJS application.  That means the HTML sent by the web server causes Javascript to run and build the dynamic contents of the web page that you see displayed.  That means, the `<div>` your are looking for with regex DOES NOT EXIST in the HTML sent by the server.  Your regex cannot find anything but its not there.

In Chrome, do Ctl+U to see what the web server sent (no "Supremacy").  Do Ctl+Shift+I and look under the "Elements" tab to see the HTML after the Javascript has done is magic (this does have "Supremacy").

This means you won't be able to get the initial HTML of the web page and scrape it to get the data you want.